# Null pointer exception with custom taglibs (Tomcat 8.0.39). jsp-api (Tomcat 8.0.39) is replaced with jsp-api (Tomcat 8.0.20) no exception is thrown

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tomcat

Tomcat version is upgraded from 8.0.20 to 8.0.39. XHTML pages which are using custom tags are throwing null pointer exception when loaded.

Custom column.jspx:

```
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="#{dropdown}">
                    <c:set var="criteriaFieldName" value="#{fieldName}_dropdown"/>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <c:set var="criteriaFieldName" value="#{fieldName}"/>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
```

I did little workout and found that **test="#{dropdown}"** throws NULL POINTER EXCEPTION (**TagAttribute.getBoolean()** as given in the exception)

Here is the block of XHTML page which uses the custom tags:

```
<src3:column label="Request #" fieldName="id" entity="#{row}"
                                            filter="#{false}" useBody="#{true}" sort="#{true}" >
                                            <h:commandLink id="requestid" value="#{row.id}" 
                                                title="#{row.id}" alt="#{row.id}" class="reqidclass"
                                                action="#{handlerBean.redirectDisplay}" onclick="revertSelectionHighlight();">
                                                <f:param name="requestId" value="#{row.id}"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="requestType" value="#{row.requestType.id}"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="pageMode" value="viewOnly"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="processId" value="#{row.processId}"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="siteid"
                                                    value="#{row.lab.building.site.id}-#{row.building.site.id}"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="buildingid"
                                                    value="#{crud.selectedBuilding.id}"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="labid" value="#{crud.selectedLab.id}"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="qcguid" value="#{crud.empItem.user.qcGuid}"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="fromPage" value="revokeAccessRequest"></f:param>
                                                <f:param name="rowIndex"
                                                    value="#{handlerBean.list.rowIndex}"></f:param>
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                        </src3:column>
```

Here is the exception root cause:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getBoolean(TagAttribute.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.isTestTrue(ChooseWhenHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:67)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.apply(ChooseWhenHandler.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseOtherwiseHandler.apply(ChooseOtherwiseHandler.java:41)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:73)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IfHandler.apply(IfHandler.java:54)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:122)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:122)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:122)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.apply(ChooseWhenHandler.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:144)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseOtherwiseHandler.apply(ChooseOtherwiseHandler.java:41)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:73)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:144)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.apply(ChooseWhenHandler.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:144)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
```

I could not figure out anything because I am new to this technology. Can anyone help!